# NoSuchMethodError : The setter 'text=' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: text="2020-12-10 00:00:00.000"

Tags: flutter, dart

I navigate to EditOrderPage and pass some data to it (using which I need to pre-fill TextFormFields)

```
onPressed: () {
 Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => EditOrderPage(
       title: "Изменить",
       date: DateTime.parse(feedbackItems[index].date)
           .toLocal()
           .toString(),
       name: feedbackItems[index].name,
       product: feedbackItems[index].product,
       quantity: feedbackItems[index].quantity,
       discount: feedbackItems[index].discount,
       delivery: feedbackItems[index].delivery,
       payment: feedbackItems[index].payment,
       paymethod: feedbackItems[index].paymethod,
     ),
   ),
 );
},
```

Then I have `EditOrderScreen` which has a state `EditOrderPage`

```
class EditOrderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Feedback Responses',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
      ),
      home: EditOrderPage(
        title: "Изменить",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _EditOrderPageState extends State<EditOrderPage> {
  ValueNotifier isActive = ValueNotifier(true);
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  TextEditingController edateController;
  TextEditingController enameController;
  TextEditingController eproductController;
  TextEditingController equantityController;
  TextEditingController ediscountController;
  TextEditingController epriceController;
  TextEditingController edeliveryController;
  TextEditingController epaymentController;
  TextEditingController epaymethodController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    edateController.text = widget.date;
    enameController.text = widget.name;
    eproductController.text = widget.product;
    equantityController.text = widget.quantity;
    ediscountController.text = widget.discount;
    epriceController.text = widget.price;
    edeliveryController.text = widget.delivery;
    epaymentController.text = widget.payment;
    epaymethodController.text = widget.paymethod;
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

What is causing the error? (Sorry..looks messy and pretty hard coded ..Just beginner in Flutter*) Thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to initialize the `TextEditingControllers`, until then they are `null`.

To initialize:

```
TextEditingController edateController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController enameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController eproductController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController equantityController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController ediscountController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController epriceController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController edeliveryController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController epaymentController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController epaymethodController = TextEditingController();
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you !

Comment: @YoqubxonXamidoff don't forget to select the answer as correct! :)